# Start Midnight Commander on iTerm2 launch

Tags: macos, iterm2

What is the best method to make sure Midnight Commander is launched whenever iTerm2 window/tab is open?

Comment: Only iTerm2 or **any** Terminal?

Comment: iTerm2 specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Profiles -> Open Profiles -> Edit Profiles -> General Tab ->` Send text as start: mc